# Expected value of (3X - 5X^2 + 1)

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, variance, expected-value

I have an exercise where I need to find the expected value of $3X - 5X^2 + 1$, and I don't know where start. I know that $E(aX + b) = a \cdot E(X) + b$, and also that $Var(X) = E(X^2) - [E(X)]^2$, but I don't know how to use these formulas. Can I have a hint on how to start? I don't need to know the PDF, but only try to expand the problem using the formulas I know.

Comment: What is the goal of the problem? To find a numerical answer? If you do not have the density of $X$ then this is not possible.

Comment: Is just $E(3X-5X^2+1) = 3E(X) - 5E(X^2) + 1 = 3E(X) - 5[Var(X)+E(X)^2]+1$ sufficient?

Comment: Yes I have the density that is x/8 for x=1,2,5. So it is not possible to calculate it without density? Because sometimes the professor give us examples like this one but without any other information

Comment: These formulas hold for discrete and continuous random variables. The PDF $P(W=1)=1/8,P(W=2)=2/8,P(W=5)=5/8$ provides the distribution of a discrete random variable with $E(W)=15/4.$ What is its variance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given a unknown disttibution with $E(X)=\mu$ and $V(x)=\sigma^2$:

$$E(3X-5X^2+1)=3E(X)-5E(X^2)+E(1)$$
$$E(3X-5X^2+1)=3E(X)-5[V(x)+E(X)^2]+E(1)$$
$$E(3X-5X^2+1)=3\mu-5[\sigma^2+\mu^2]+1$$
$$E(3X-5X^2+1)=3\mu-5\sigma^2-5\mu^2+1$$

I consider the full expression of **@corey979** is the answer but it needs $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$.

Comment: Serious question, does it really _need_ $\mu$ and $\sigma$? Doesn't it suffice to write $E(X)$ and $\text{Var}(X)$?

Comment: @Seankala That is what intro stats said about expectation and variance and that could be creating confusion in user, also \mu and \sigma^2 are more known in literature term of stat methodology.

Comment: @Duck thank you so much, so simply I have to take the expected of each parameter and then I can evolve the expression such that I'll have variance and mean that I can calculate? Yes I know that  is the mean or the expected value and ^2 is the variance.

Comment: So what's keeping you from clicking to Accept this fine answer (along with your thanks)?

Comment: @BruceET I already did it, but it cannot be shown because I have less than 15 reputation (:

Comment: @BruceET The answer you posted is so cool. More practical than only formulaes.

Comment: @ElenaFranchini Hi dear, I believe you, if you want for sure, can accept the answer like this ticking the tick on the left side of the answer https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer many thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

**Comment:** Just a reality check with a particular example: Let $X \sim\mathsf{Pois}(\lambda=3),$ so that $\mu = \sigma^2= 3.$ Let $Y = 3X-5X^2 + 1,$ and
find $E(Y).$ With 10 million realizations of $Y,$ one can expect three significant digits of accuracy.

```
set.seed(2020)
x = rpois(10^7, 3)
y = 3*x - 5*x^2 + 1 
mean(x);  var(x)
[1] 3.00072     # aprx E(X) = 3
[1] 3.000116    # aprx V(X) = 3
mean(3*x) - mean(5*(x^2)) + 1
[1] -50.02001   # aprx E(Y) = -50
mean(y)
[1] -50.02001   # aprx E(Y) = -50
3*3 - 5*3 - 5*3^2 + 1
[1] -50         # exact E(Y)
```

---

**Addendum** re the discrete random variable discussed in Comments.
I will let you show exact numerical values corresponding to
simulated values, if interested.

```
set.seed(1219)
w = sample(c(1,2,5), 10^7, rep=T, p=c(1,2,5)/8)
v = 3*w - 5*w^2 + 1 
mean(w);  var(w)
[1] 3.750773  # aprx E(W) = 15/4 = 3.75
[1] 2.686251
mean(3*w) - mean(5*(w^2)) + 1
[1] -71.52042 # @ Duck's solution
mean(v)
[1] -71.52042 # Directly
```